# REST Api Add item to list in App Web

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-online, sharepoint-addin, rest

I have an app that contains a few lists within its own app web. I need to add new items thru the REST Api. The problem is when I try to add an item I get a

> 403 Forbidden error

Which is odd because I thought the app had full control over its own app web. Please advise.

**AJAX**

```
var def = new jQuery.Deferred();            

var executor = new SP.RequestExecutor(_spPageContextInfo.siteAbsoluteUrl);
var data = { __metadata: { type: 'SP.Data.ProductsListItem' } };
data = jQuery.extend({}, data, product);
data = JSON.stringify(data);

console.log('Product Request Body: \n' + data);

executor.executeAsync({
    url: urlBase + "/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('Products')/items",
    method: "POST",
    body: data,
    headers: {
        "accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
        "content-type": "application/json;odata=verbose",
        "X-RequestDigest": jQuery("#__REQUESTDIGEST").val()
    },
    success: function (results) {
        def.resolve(results);
    },
    error: function (results) {
        def.reject(results);
    }
});

return def.promise();
```

**Error**

It looks like the request isn't going to the proper web? But I'm setting the context to `_spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl`, which gives me the correct URL I want.

[image: Network Panel Output]

**Permissions**

There aren't any permission bc I thought apps OOB had Full Control of the app web???

[image: Permissions Tab]

Comment: What permission you have provided for the app? Check the Permission tab

Comment: Updated with permission tab. I haven't set any but that's bc I thought the app had full control of the app web. That's where the list is.

Comment: Try to give Full Permission

Comment: I was setting the `SP.RequestExecutor` to the Site context instead of the Web... Thanks for your help.

Comment: @ExceptionLimeCat Just to confirm, you resolved this issue? If so, can you post an answer detailing your resolution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My issue was caused by setting my `SP.RequestExecutor` context to the site collection instead of the App Web.

```
 var executor = new SP.RequestExecutor(_spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl);
```

Thanks for everyone's help.